# What are examples of naturally dense graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

Graphs are very useful for modeling real-world phenomena and relationships.

Broadly, graph data structures and algorithms are divided into two categories:

- Those useful for *sparse* graphs (e.g. [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm))
- Those useful for *dense* graphs (e.g. [adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)).

However, in every situation I can think of, real-world graphs are sparse. For example:

1. Web networks form sparse graphs (every site links to a *few* other sites)
2. Social networks form sparse graphs (every person is knows a *few* other people)
3. Electrical networks form sparse graphs (most circuit elements only affect only a *few* others nearby)
4. Road networks form sparse graphs (every road links to a *few* other roads)

(Note that "few" is in comparison to the *total* number of sites/people/elements/roads/etc.)

However, I've never found a use case for algorithms and data structures for *dense* graphs.
Every graph I remember ever encountering has turned out to be sparse.

#### What kinds of *real-world* graphs would I need to use *dense* graph algorithms for?

**Please note:** Yes, I know that a small group of people in which everyone knows each other forms a dense graph, but that's **not** the kind of situation I'm asking about, because:

1. Social network software is never written for just a handful of people
2. *Any* algorithm works just fine with small data; there's no need for dense-graph algorithms.

That means I'm also not looking for silly examples like "the complement of a sparse graph" either.
Yes, those are dense, but unless you can give me an example of a problem that would be of practical interest and which would *not* be reasonable solved with the original sparse graph, that's not going to answer my question.

Comment: The brain is made up [of multiple separate areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain#Functional_divisions).  Some of these are physically connected, some are not.  This network is called the [connectome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectome).  It is a dense graph (clearly over 50%), but not a complete one.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of a sparse graph is a dense one (think of all the sites a given web page *doesn't* link to).  So there's a start.

Off the top of my head...

- Small social networks (e.g. people in a club probably are Facebook friends with most of the others in the club)
- The transitive closure of a graph, or at least partially (e.g. a friend of a friend)
- Really badly-written/tightly-coupled code (imagine a directed graph where class A points to class B if A references B; maybe as a member, a return value for a method, etc.)

More generally, try relaxing certain travel constraints if you want denser graphs.

Comment: I think you subtly missed the point of the question. I can certainly *come up* with examples of dense graphs and describe what they resemble in the real world; that's not the problem. The problem is that I would never be actually using dense-graph algorithms to deal with those graphs in practice, because they're not problems that are of interest in the real world. (Or, the problems themselves are already small enough that anything works well for them, as is the case in your first example.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the denser a graph becomes, the closer it gets to being complete, and a complete graph with weighted edges is usually easier to represent and think about simply as a square matrix, with perhaps some infinities or negative infinities scattered around to represent missing "edges".  Alternatively it may become close to a complete bipartite graph, which can also be represented as a matrix (just one that uses different sets of labels along the two axes.)  So e.g. the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) is usually represented as a problem about a matrix, rather than about a dense edge-weighted bipartite graph.

I think one reason to use dense graph algorithms is to guarantee good worst-case behaviour on dense graphs.

Also there are some problems that are related to other problems on the complement of a graph -- i.e. the graph in which every pair of vertices has an edge between them iff they didn't have an edge between them in the original.  E.g. if you're looking for the maximum clique in a graph that contains more than, say, 30% of all possible edges (really guessing here), and you think this clique will be large, you're probably better off creating the complement graph and then looking for a [minimum vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of it, since the complement of such a vertex cover in the complement graph will be a clique in the original graph.  Although both problems are NP-hard, minimum vertex cover is much faster when a small cover exists, taking O(1.2378^k*n^O(1)) for a cover of size k (corresponding to a clique of size n-k) versus O(1.1888^n) for maximum clique.

Comment: There's nice information in your answer but I'm not sure it actually answers the question I was asking. For example, *why* would I be looking for a clique on the complement of a sparse graph? What might it physically represent that is interesting? It's easy enough for me to come up with examples, but they'd all be random mathematical problems, not representing any graphs that come up in practice.

Comment: As I said, I think problems on dense graphs are usually presented as problems on matrices; they're isomorphic.  So I think asking why there seem to be no dense graph problems in nature is like asking why there seem to be no adults under the age of 16: it's because we call those people something else ;)  Another way to put it: algorithms for dense graphs are "really" algorithms for matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that. Do you really think of Floyd-Warshall as a matrix algorithm? I always think of it in terms of graphs...

Comment: As do I, because it's presented that way.  As to why, I'd guess that algorithms will tend to be presented as dense graph algorithms, rather than as matrix algorithms, when they solve the dense version of a problem that already makes sense as a "natural" sparse problem.  But there's really no fundamental *mathematical* distinction between dense weighted graphs and matrices.

Comment: Yeah there's no mathematical distinction,  but still... I feel like I "know it when I see it",  so to speak. For example,  PageRank is presented as a graph problem, but I intuitively think of the algorithm (which is basically an eigendecomposition) as a matrix algorithm, not as a graph one...

Comment: One way to make the matrix/graph distinction more rigorous might be to determine it makes sense for multiple edges to exist between the same pairs of vertices. Matrices fundamentally don't allow for this scenario, so if you have a "matrix algorithm", it won't work for graph problems of this nature (e.g. this can happen for road networks, but not for social networks). But a "graph algorithm" probably won't care and will just work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

One example that I can think of is cryptocurrency where every currency can be converted to every other currency. To keep track of all conversion rates as the market fluctuates, you would need a dense graph representation and algorithm.